# Postgresql join on same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table looking like a block history:

```
id  user_id admin_id    when_blocked    block   reason
1   1       4           05.05.17        TRUE    flood
2   1       4           06.05.17        FALSE   
3   1       4           07.05.17        TRUE    flood
4   1       4           08.05.17        FALSE   
5   1       5           09.05.17        TRUE    cheating
```

Where `block` column means block action (`TRUE` as block, `FALSE` as unblock). New `block` record may appear, only if previously `user` was unblocked. Therefore, records with same `user_id` always alternate between `TRUE` and `FALSE`.

**The problem:**

I want to get table looking like:

```
user_id admin_id    when_blocked    reason   when_unblocked
1       4           05.05.17        flood    06.05.17       
1       4           07.05.17        flood    08.05.17     
1       5           09.05.17        cheating null
```

Is there a possibility to implement this resulting table?

Thanks.

Comment: It's more of an aggregation than a join, but the main question is how to determine which rows relate to each other.  What are the definitive rules that mean rows 1, 2, 3, 4 don't all merge together, and in-fact are grouped as 1&2, 3&4?  Does `block = TRUE` always precede `block = FALSE` in date order?  Can you ever get `TRUE, TRUE, FALSE` or `FALSE, FALSE, FALSE`?  Or is it always nice and perfectly clean, always starting with `TRUE` and then always alternating?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just want `lead()`, but a subquery is also needed:

```
select user_id, admin_id, when_blocked, reason, next_when_blocked as when_unblocked
from (select bh.*,
             lead(when_blocked) over (partition by user_id, admin_id order by id) as next_when_blocked
      from block_history bh
     ) bh
where block;
```

This assumes that the values are interleaved -- as in your example and as implied by your explanation.

Comment: I think you also need include `admin_id` in the partition.

Comment: I would order by `when_blocked` rather than `id`...  Or am I overly pessimistic, or just mistaken? *(Defining `previous` and `next` by time ordering rather than surrogate key ordering...)*

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - Reading the OP again, I can imagine possible cases where AdminX blocks a user then AdminY unblocks them.  Also, the notion of an alternating sequence should hold *(according to the op)* for the duration of a `user`, adding `admin_id` should be superfluous?

Comment: @MatBailie For how is build the data I dont think make any difference on this case

Comment: @MatBailie . . . You would be trusting that `when_blocked` is actually stored in a native date/time format, even though the column values could easily be strings.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6N1EaoeAmegfdvgg9ELDHn/0

```
select distinct on (coalesce(unblocked_id, id))
    user_id, admin_id, when_blocked, reason, when_unblocked
from
    (select * from history where block) b
    left join
    (
        select id as unblocked_id, when_blocked as when_unblocked
        from history
        where not block
    ) nb on b.id < nb.unblocked_id
order by coalesce(unblocked_id, id), id
;
 user_id | admin_id | when_blocked |  reason  | when_unblocked 
---------+----------+--------------+----------+----------------
       1 |        4 | 2017-05-05   | flood    | 2017-05-06
       1 |        4 | 2017-05-05   | flood    | 2017-05-08
       1 |        5 | 2017-05-09   | cheating |
```

Answer (score 0):

I like Gordon Linoffs answer with `lead`, and it might be faster if the table has very many rows, but I think this select is easier to wrap one's head around:

```
select user_id, admin_id, when_blocked, reason,
  ( select min(when_blocked)
    from history
    where not block
    and user_id = h.user_id
    and when_blocked >= h.when_blocked ) when_unblocked
from history h
where block
order by when_blocked, user_id;
```

Column when_blocked should be of type date or timestamp for `>=` to work.